# Creating dataset from loops

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I created small dataset, can find below:

[image: sample data]

Later formed groups using CIQ column (using pandas group by syntax):

[image: Group Data]

Entire code:

'''

```
fd = pd.read_csv("C:....\Test.csv")

coder_gr = fd.groupby(["CIQ"])
print(coder_gr.first())

for x, y in coder_gr:
    y.Date.duplicated()
```

'''

Now I checked duplicates inside each group using for loop:

[image: Duplicate check ouput]

But I want output entire group dataset output plus along with duplicate loop output, for that I tried below code:

```
emp = []

for x, y in coder_gr:
    emp.append(y)
    emp.append(y.Date.duplicated())
```

output look like:

[image: final output]

***Desired output***:

[image: desired ouput]

Not getting output in proper format. I don't know how to set proper output.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)
for x, y in coder_gr:
    print(y)
    print(y.Date.duplicated())
```

Comment: Hello Aarjav, thanks for quick reply, after using above code I am getting output first group dataset (y) then in next row  getting duplicated values. But I want duplicate value result as column in "y" dataset itself. Above added required output, please have a look once.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer:

```
emp = pd.DataFrame()

for x, y in coder_gr:
    emp = emp.append(pd.series(y), ignore_index=True)
    emp = emp.append(y)
```